# How to build Flyway without all JDBC Drivers

Tags: flyway

I found an issue with FlyWay running in a Weblogic Server.

I cloned the source repository and added the unit test + fix. But I can't test my fix in Weblogic because of all the JDBC drivers needed by the maven build and that are not available in public repos.

Is there a simple way to bypass these dependencies ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As decribed in the [**How To Contribute**](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/wiki/HowToContribute) wiki page:

Disable the MediumTests Maven profile using **-P-MediumTests**.

Ex.: `mvn clean install -P-MediumTests`

Comment: I missed the - symbol to disable the profile. Sorry and thank you

Comment: No worries! Looking forward to your fix!

Comment: I tried running this but the build fails when building the appengine module. It cannot find the google_sql dependency in the public repo.

Comment: This was an oversight. Fixed.